# Activating tabs via navigation and adding class to navigation button clicked

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have a navigation bar that has selections for individual tabs on a page so if a user click on tab one in navigation bar it would open the page and activate the corresponding tab.  The tab selection on the page works fine - click on tab and content shows while changing the highlight for that tab.  The issue is when using the navigation bar it changes the content but does not change the highlight nor does it add the class to the navigation button. Any help would be much appreciated, I have been pulling my hair out on this for too long now.

code here in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/thyt6gff/1/
jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('#menu li ul a').on('click', function(e)  {

    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs 
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    //this is not working
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    //Change the class for navigation bar
    //this is not working
    $('#menu li ul a ' + currentAttrValue).addClass('current')

    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();


    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});


});
```

html:

```
<div id="header">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="current">test page</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="test.html" class="current">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
<section class="multilevel">

<br>
<!-----tabs----->    
<div class="tabs">  
<ul class="tab-links">
<li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab1" class="tab active"> 
<h2>tab 1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor. Aliquam euismod at lectus non malesuada. Proin in luctus purus. Sed dictum leo vitae est gravida consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
<h2>tab 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor. .</p>
<p>Aenean sit amet hendrerit ex, a viverra nisi. Vivamus augue neque, sollicitudin eget sem non, commodo cursus orci. Ut facilisis justo nec sapien aliquam, non malesuada tortor congue.</p>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
<h2>tab 3</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas consectetur malesuada egestas. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi et interdum. Mauris et pellentesque eros, hendrerit vehicula dolor.</p>
<p>Aenean sit amet hendrerit ex, a viverra nisi. Vivamus augue neque, sollicitudin eget sem non, commodo cursus orci. Ut facilisis justo nec sapien aliquam, non malesuada tortor congue. Vivamus mollis accumsan maximus. </p>
<p>Integer velit lacus, placerat sit amet ornare sit amet, mattis non mi. Nulla faucibus tristique lectus id semper. Pellentesque porta libero a tempus pretium. Integer non ex at urna convallis accumsan eu id dui.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!----/tabs----->
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please elaborate little more? I cant find any problem :/

Comment: Does the page refreshes when you click on the navigation links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adriancarriger/0ds3qobz/)**

It looks like your selectors weren't matching any `li` elements in the `.tab-links` block, which is where you want to change your classes.

**Remove this:**

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
$('#menu li ul a ' + currentAttrValue).addClass('current');
```

**Replace with this:**

```
 $('.tabs .tab-links li').removeClass('active');
 $('.tab-links a[href$="' + currentAttrValue + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks so much adriancarriger,  i put this in but found another issue
from index.html > use main navigation to open text.html to specific tab(tab2 or tab 3)using the appropriate navigation button
the code only seems to work on the test page, external from that page does nothing 

i do not want it to jump down the page, I want it to only load the page, update the highlighted tab and tab content

nav > index.html  test.html
      tab1
      tab2
      tab3

Answer (score 0):

You already have a working click event for the 'tab-links class'. You could just bind the drop down list to trigger the tab-links related click event.

HTML

```
            <ul class="symbolic">
                <li><a href="test.html" class="current">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab1">tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">tab 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab3">tab 3</a></li>
            </ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('ul.symbolic li a').click(function(){
    var tabId = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tabs .tab-links a[href='+tabId+']').trigger('click');
});

// Trigger Initial Click of tab 1 on page load
$('.tabs .tab-links a[href=#tab1]').trigger('click');

});
```

This way you can even click tab1 on page load!
[Working Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thyt6gff/3/)